# Not able to declare a global variable in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to make a quiz with tkinter and python classes(I have never used classes). Does anyone have a explanation to why I am getting this error "PS C:\Users\user_name> & python "c:/python projects/tkinter_w_classes.py"
File "c:/python projects/tkinter_w_classes.py", line 17
global selected = 'a'
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

```
class Question():
    def __init__(self,question, op_a,op_b,op_c,op_d, answer):
        self.question = question
        self.op_a = op_a
        self.op_b = op_b
        self.op_c = op_c
        self.op_d = op_d
        self.answer = answer

        def makewin(self):
            root = tk.Tk()
            root.geometry('500x500')

            def bexea():
                global selected = 'a'

                if selected == answer:
                    global score += 1

            def bexeb():
                 selected = 'b'
                if selected == answer:
                    score += 1

            def bexec():
                 selected = 'c'
                if selected == answer:
                    score += 1

            def bexed():
                 selected = 'd'
                if selected == answer:
                    score += 1

            ql = tk.Label(text=question).pack()
            ba = tk.Button(text=op_a,command=bexea).pack()
            bb = tk.Button(text=op_b,command=bexeb).pack()
            bc = tk.Button(text=op_c,command=bexec).pack()
            bd = tk.Button(text=op_d,command=bexed).pack()
 
q1 = Question()

q1('What is 2 + 2', '1', '2', '3', '4', '4')

q1.makewin()
```

Answer (score 1):

A `global` statement cannot perform assignment; it *just* marks the name as global, rather than local.  All `global` statements must appear at the start of the function.

```
    def bexea():
        global selected, score
        selected = 'a'
        if answer == selected:
            score += 1
```

There is little reason to make `selected` global, though. No function looks at what value it may have received previously; they all simply set a new value and use that. If you define `selected` at all, it can simply be a local variable.

```
        def bexea():
            global score
            selected = 'a'

            if selected == answer:
                score += 1
```

There are other issues with your class design (including the use of *any* global variables), but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to complete this with your advice

Answer (score 0):

```
class Question():
    selectecd = ''
    
    def markSelected(self):
        self.selected = 'a'
    
    def printSelected(self):
        print(self.selected)
```

This should be a proper class based approach. Don't use global ... it should be enough to have it in a instance based scope.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to complete this with your advice